OSPF Stub Networks and Loopback Interfaces
I have a question about Stub Networks in RouterLSA in OSPF for Loopback interfaces.
In RFC we can read: "If the state of the interface is Loopback, add a Type 3
link (stub network) as long as this is not an interface
to an unnumbered point-to-point network. The Link ID
should be set to the IP interface address, the Link Data
set to the mask 0xffffffff (indicating a host route),
and the cost set to 0." Howewer, I have seen in real traffic LSA (just an example) with Advertising Router RID 195.161.1.194 and having Stub Network with LinkID 195.161.1.194, mask /32 and metric = 1. Can I be sure that it is a Loopback Interface? Also, in RFC we can read that Stub Network with mask /32 can be generated for "IP hosts
that are directly connected to the router (e.g., via a SLIP
line)." So, is there a way to exactly deside whether it is Loopback interface or not just by looking to LSA?

OSPF has no idea what type of interface the network represents. OSPF is only concerned with networks. Interfaces from which the networks are derived can be of physical or logical (loopbacks, SVIs, physical interface subinterfaces, etc.). OSPF does not know or care about the interface.

@RonMaupin Thank you for your answer. I'm not very experienced in this area, could you please provide an example where mask in stub network is /32 and it is directly connected host. What meaning will LinkID have in such situation? I'm trying to do network mapping based on different protocols (OSPF too) and don't know how to interpret Stub Networks with /32 masks correctly.
